# Is there an antonym for "improve on"?

Tags: word-request

I can't find one in the dictionary.

There is a word "disimprove" so "disimprove on" is a catachresis waiting to happen. I think it would be easily understood. But I'm looking for an existing word.

The question presupposes an understanding of the difference between "improve" and "improve on." Here are two examples I feel are correct:

1. I want to improve my GPA.
2. I want to improve on my last year's GPA.

In both examples I am comparing my current GPA to my previous GPA. But "improve" is used for the thing being compared (current GPA) and "improve on" for the thing being compared *to* (previous GPA).

If the difference is between the subject of a comparison and the object of one, it seems to me that "improve" has multiple antonyms but "improve on" doesn't have even one.

Comment: +1 Very tricky question. I can think of *deteriorate or worsen* but could not find what is the negative of 'I will have to improve on English grammar.'

Comment: That's a great question! Therefore I was searching for a solution: it seems that the antonym always depends on the context.

Comment: degrade   debase   corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

This is very tricky. We actually have "**improve on**" as "*make better than before*" which is actually in meaning equal to "*make something better than the current thing taking the current thing as a starting point*" in most cases.

Thus your usage of "*I want to improve on my last year's GPA*" means "*To write a new GPA which is better than last year's (but take last year's GPA as an example)*" and probably not "*change the old last year's GPA to make it better (having the same GPA edited)*"

And if look at this in such a way we see that you need to use a word or phrase that means "*to make something new in a worse way from something old*". Otherwise, if look at it as "*to make beneficial additions or changes to something in order to make it better*" then we need a word or phrase that means "*to make detrimental additions or changes to something in order to make it worse*".

Google shows up a few instances of "**disimprove on**" which I doubt is very common but is likely to be the only possible correct antonym to "**improve on**":

- To **disimprove on** Ezra Pound’s catchy aphorism, “Literature is news that stays news”: “Great obits are the last news fit to print.” - [The joy of obituaries](http://www.broadstreetreview.com/cross-cultural/The_joy_of_obituaries#)
- Years ago I came to the view that movies as often improve on books as **disimprove on** them. - [Industry Talk in Frankfurt: The Dynamics of Adapting Books to Film](https://publishingperspectives.com/2017/10/industry-talk-dynamics-adapting-books-film/)
- Race winnings are trivial, they are always the same for that driver unless they improve or **disimprove on** their results. - [[Q3 Suggestion] Sponsor Mixup - iGP Manager](http://[Q3%20Suggestion]%20Sponsor%20Mixup%20-%20iGP%20Manager)

Purely in this context you could use the words "[impair](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impair)" or "[worsen](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worsen)".

Out of context it's better to search for a certain word that is a synonym of "**disimprove**" but with definition that fits your particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

Destroy or ruin might be somewhat antonyms. (Remember that antonyms are almost never direct opposites of the word unless they are exactly related.) For example:

"I want to destroy my GPA."

"I want to ruin my GPA."

Comment: So, what would be your antonym sentences for the following?
1. My son improves me. (I.e., my son makes me a better person.)
2. My son improves on me. (I.e., my son is a better version of the old man.)

Comment: @M.Borns The antonym can be "My son diminishes me" and "My son becomes worse than I am"